# Find the first word using pattern group

Tags: java, regex

I am having problem in finding first word in below file names.

```
12345.pdf ,
12345 203 1525345.pdf ,
12345_xxx.pdf ,
12345-xxx.pdf ,
12345 203-1525345.pdf ,
Smith 12345 03012016.pdf ,
Smith 12345 03012016-1.pdf
```

I am using pattern `({ln}\\w+?)[_\\s-](\\w+?_)?({dc}\\w+?).(\\w+)`  and fetching value of key ln (`value = matcher.group("ln")`).

Please help.

This is my program and every time i need value ln as first word only.

```
    String[] fileName ={"12345.pdf","12345 203    1525345.pdf","12345_xxx.pdf","12345-xxx.pdf","12345 203-1525345.pdf","Smith 12345 03012016.pdf","Smith 12345 03012016-1.pdf"};
    String pat =  "({ln}\\w+?)[_\\s-](\\w+?[_\\s-])?({dc}\\w+?).(\\w+)";
    Pattern fileNamePattern = new Pattern(pat);
    for(String fileName1 : fileName)
    {
    Matcher matcher = fileNamePattern.matcher(fileName1);
    String value = null;
    if (matcher.matches())
    {
        value = matcher.group("ln");
    }
    System.out.print(fileName1 +" : ");
    System.out.println(value);
    }

}
```

}

and values :-

```
12345.pdf : 12345
12345 203 1525345.pdf : 12345
12345_xxx.pdf :12345
12345-xxx.pdf : 12345 
12345 203-1525345.pdf : 12345
Smith 12345 03012016.pdf : smith
Smith 12345 03012016-1.pdf :smith
```

Comment: What is the Output you get and what is the expected Output?

Comment: Please look at my program.. i want value of key ln as first word ..

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\b|_)
```

You can simply use this with `multiline` mode.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/kZ2iZ8/1

Answer (score 0):

Use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and `^` [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

```
^\b[\w\.\d\-]+\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gD2sE9/1)